# Click to animate accordion to top of screen

Tags: javascript

I would like to animate the clicked accordion item to the top of the page. The first click works, but everything after seems to accumulate and makes the accordion slide up and out of view. The correct functionality would be each item  scrolling to the exact spot as the previous, in a fixed position from the top of the window. Part of the issue is that I am using a prototype and not sure how to stop the accumulation of clicks each time an instance is created.

```js
var media = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px")
    
    var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
      this.el = el || {}
      this.multiple = multiple || false
    
      var links = this.el.find('.link')
    
      links.on('click', {el: this.el, multiple: this.multiple}, this.dropdown)
    }
    
    Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
      var $el = e.data.el
          $this = $(this)
          $next = $this.next()
    
      $next.slideToggle()
      $this.parent().toggleClass('open')
    
      if(!e.data.multiple) {
        $el.find('.content').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open')
      }
    
      if(media.matches) {
        $("html, body").animate({ 
          scrollTop: $this.offset().top - 85
        }, 900)
      }
    }
    
    var accordion = new Accordion($('.hollow-accordion-03 #accordion'), false)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="hollow-accordion-03">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <ul id="accordion">
      <li>
        <div class="link">
          <i class="fa fa-database"></i>
          <h3>First List Item</h3>
          <div class="state-wrap">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <p>This is filler content for the list item. Content in this section will be replaced by copy for your site. This is filler text. Content in this section will be replaced by copy for your site. This is filler text.</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="link">
          <i class="fa fa-database"></i>
          <h3>Second List Item</h3>
          <div class="state-wrap">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <p>This is filler content for the list item. Content in this section will be replaced by copy for your site. This is filler text. Content in this section will be replaced by copy for your site. This is filler text.</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="link">
          <i class="fa fa-database"></i>
          <h3>Third List Item</h3>
          <div class="state-wrap">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <p>This is filler content for the list item. Content in this section will be replaced by copy for your site. This is filler text. Content in this section will be replaced by copy for your site. This is filler text.</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="link">
          <i class="fa fa-database"></i>
          <h3>Fourth List Item</h3>
          <div class="state-wrap">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <p>This is filler content for the list item. Content in this section will be replaced by copy for your site. This is filler text. Content in this section will be replaced by copy for your site. This is filler text.</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```